# Is this truth table correct (4 AND with 3 inputs each)?

Tags: logic

I was given a circuit diagram which I am supposed to construct a truth table of.

[image: OP's circuit diagram]

Can someone confirm is my truth table correct?

[image: OP's truth table]

Comment: Please type up the question instead of asking people to click through (twice).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

The final expression is equal to NOT(C) (see derivation bellow), which you have correctly expressed in your truth table.

\begin{align}
&\overline{A}\overline{B}\overline{C}+\overline{A}B\overline{C}+A\overline{B}\overline{C}+AB\overline{C}\\
&=\overline{C}(\overline{A}\overline{B}+\overline{A}B+A\overline{B}+AB)\\
&=\overline{C}(\overline{A}(\overline{B}+B)+A(\overline{B}+B))\\
&=\overline{C}(\overline{A}+A)\\
&=\overline{C}
\end{align}